# How to resize the Dialog Box?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I would like to resize my dialogbox so for every dialog box i will have to size the full screnn size and the second use fill_parent for the size. my dilag is defined by the layout given by the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_back"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/parcourstextV0"
                style="@style/presentation_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="Parcours antérieur"
                android:textColor="@color/black02"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/parcoursClose"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                android:text="x"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:typeface="normal"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listparcours"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

can you help me please.

Comment: what you want i am not getting from your question?

Comment: resize  the dilogbox.

Comment: then explain correctly in your question what changes you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_back"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/parcourstextV0"
                    style="@style/presentation_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                    android:text="Parcours antérieur"
                    android:textColor="@color/black02"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/parcoursClose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                android:text="x"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:typeface="normal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listparcours"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```